Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language & Usage Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

How to say properly translate "circulation"?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)  
webpage loading.. 加载 vs 载入​​​​​​​
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
What is the difference between 們 and 们 for marking plurals?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)  
How is pronunciation discussed in Chinese?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Why don't all questions have the "ma" 吗 particle at the end?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)  
Learn the characters at the same time as the language?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Is there a Chinese equivalent of the German "Mut zur Lücke"?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
How can I express the concept "There's nothing of which I'm absolutely sure" in Chinese?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Can I use a rare character like 飂 in a name?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Can whether a character is simplified or traditional depend on the context it is used in?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  

